IIS Reverse Proxy For TCP Backend (None HTTP)
I have a backend TCP websocket which I need to run using port 443 so it will be served from the same domain which is hosted on IIS and which also run over port 443, searching online is proposing to use IIS reverse proxy through ARR/URL-Rewrite but it seems they only support HTTP(S) while the websocket is based on TCP protocol, so is this possible that IIS act as reverse proxy for TCP protocol and not HTTP?

So, IIS by itself can't handle TCP stuff—it's really only good for HTTP/HTTPS. What you're looking for is outside its comfort zone. If you need to run a TCP WebSocket on port 443, you’re better off using something like NGINX or HAProxy.
These guys can handle both HTTP/S and TCP traffic, so they can forward your WebSocket connections to the backend without a hitch.
Another option is to just stick your WebSocket on a different subdomain (like ws.yourdomain.com) or port if that’s an option for you—avoids the whole reverse proxy headache on the same port.
But yeah, IIS won't cut it for TCP, so you’ll need to bring in another tool if you’re set on using port 443.

Sad to hear that, but how about this net.tcp thing in IIS? some people online says it works some says no, see for example this link which has both views: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/answers/questions/1162500/how-to-setup-reverse-proxy-in-iis-for-non-http-por

Personally I think it is a bad choice of design to mix layer 4 and 7 in your solution. I would recommend to revisit your requirements.
